# TouchableOpacity called everytime when i press on Textinput

Tags: javascript, ajax, react-native, input

**The login function calling every time whenever I press on either Text input field**

Touchable statement:

```
<TouchableOpacity
     style={InputFieldStyle.submitButton}
     onPress={this.login(this.state.email, this.state.password)}>
          <Text style={InputFieldStyle.submitButtonText}>Submit Me</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Login function:

```
login = (email, pass) => {
     alert(`Email: ${email} Password: ${pass}`);
};
```

[**This is my expo link where I'm working on Textinput**](https://snack.expo.io/@sunil-ghodela/react-native-inputfield)

Is there any way to stop it or am i doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`login()` is an arrow function so you don't need to `bind()` it. The actual problem is the `onPress` prop on your `TouchableOpacity`. This prop should be a function to be invoked whenever the button is pressed.

Instead of passing a function, you are *invoking the login() function* in your `render()` and passing the return value (undefined) to the button. The behaviour you are seeing is `login()` called every time that `render()` is.

The solution will be to change:

`<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.login(this.state.email, this.state.password)} {...otherProps}>`

to

`<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {this.login(this.state.email, this.state.password)}} {...otherProps}>`

Comment: this is the must bad answer to this question.
This way you have to make two functions for every event this way make your code unreadable and decrease your app performance for the big apps.
because you call two function to do one thing every time

Answer (score 1):

Even if the accepted answer is working, it isn't really a good practice. Binding things in your render isn't a good idea (even if it works), and makes the code harder to read in the future.

Plus, why do you need to pass the email and the password as params since you already have them is your state?

Doing so, you only duplicate some data and you can easely be lost in a more complexe code.

One easy way to fix your issue in a cleaner way would be:

```
login = () => {
  const { email, password } = this.state
  alert(`Email: ${email} Password: ${password}`);
}

//render
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.login}>
```

Answer (score 0):

Import TextInput from 'react-native' and use it instead of InputField and by using setState, entire email and password will be submitted only once when you click on submit. For reference look at this https://snack.expo.io/HkmsuZ6Dm. This will also help you fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

make it an arrow function like this 
.
onPress={()=>this.login()}
.
then it'll only called when you pressed something.

Answer (score -1):

You have a problem in
`onPress={this.login(this.state.email, this.state.password)`

You have to use `bind()` method and pass `this` keyword as the first param like this `onPress={this.login.bind(this, this.state.email, this.state.password)}`

[Read more about bind() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

But you don't have to pass the email and the password as params you can access them directly from the state

Edit your method to make it seems like:

```
login = () => {
  const { email, password } = this.state;
  alert(`Email: ${email} Password: ${password}`);
}
```

And your touchable to seems like:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.login}>
```